# Oracle SQL Query - Help Please

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm putting together a query which references a table via an alias on numerous occasions, but it then proceeds to state:

*ORA-00904: "MPAN_STATUS"."MPANCORE": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 43 Column: 126*

The query is as follows:

```
SELECT readings.mpancore, mtds.meterid, (SELECT CASE
                                                  WHEN meter_type 
                                                  LIKE 'RCAM%' AND
                                                       retrieval_method = 'R'
                                                  THEN 'TRUE' 
                                                  ELSE 'FALSE' END
                                                  FROM edmgr.mtds
                                                 WHERE meter_removed IS NULL) "IS_SMART",
                                          (SELECT CASE 
                                                  WHEN flowversion = 'D0010'          AND
                                                       readings.filename IS NOT NULL  AND
                                                       readings.filedate >= mpan_status.ssd 
                                                  THEN 'TRUE' 
                                                  ELSE 'FALSE' END
                                                  FROM edmgr.readings, edmgr.mpan_status
                                                 WHERE readings.mpancore = mpan_status.mpancore) "D0010_RECEIVED",
                                          (SELECT CASE 
                                                  WHEN effective_from_date >= mpan_status.ssd AND
                                                       dc_id = mpan_status.confirmed_dc_id          
                                                  THEN 'TRUE' 
                                                  ELSE 'FALSE' END
                                                  FROM edmgr.D0019_reg, edmgr.mpan_status) "D0019_RECEIVED",
                                          (SELECT CASE 
                                                  WHEN file_date_time <= SYSDATE-409       
                                                  THEN 'TRUE' 
                                                  ELSE 'FALSE' END
                                                  FROM edmgr.D0019_reg) "RF_READ",
                                          (SELECT CASE 
                                                  WHEN file_date_time <= SYSDATE-220       
                                                  THEN 'TRUE' 
                                                  ELSE 'FALSE' END
                                                  FROM edmgr.D0019_reg) "R3_READ",
                                          (SELECT CASE 
                                                  WHEN file_date_time <= SYSDATE-118       
                                                  THEN 'TRUE' 
                                                  ELSE 'FALSE' END
                                                  FROM edmgr.D0019_reg) "R2_READ",
                                          (SELECT CASE 
                                                  WHEN file_date_time <= SYSDATE-56        
                                                  THEN 'TRUE' 
                                                  ELSE 'FALSE' END
                                                  FROM edmgr.D0019_reg) "R1_READ"   
        FROM edmgr.mpan_status "mpan_status" LEFT JOIN edmgr.D0019_reg "D0019"   ON mpan_status.mpancore = D0019.metering_system_id
                                             LEFT JOIN edmgr.readings "readings" ON mpan_status.mpancore = readings.mpancore
                                             LEFT JOIN edmgr.mtds "mtds"         ON readings.mpancore    = mtds.mpancore 
                                                   AND D0019.metering_system_id                          = mtds.mpancore
                                                   AND mtds.meterid                                      = readings.meterid
```

I'm a complete novice really, so any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start off defining the [ORA-00904 error](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00904_string_invalid_identifier.htm):

> ORA-00904 string: invalid identifier
>   Cause: The column name entered is either missing or invalid.
>
> Action: Enter a valid column name. A valid column name must begin with a letter, be less than or equal to 30 characters, and consist of only alphanumeric characters and the special characters $, _, and #.
>
> If it contains other characters, then it must be enclosed in double quotation marks. It may not be a reserved word.

Also it would be a **case-sensitivity** issue (where you put mpan_status in quotes, in the FROM argument.) In Oracle, column names are case-sensitive only when you put them in quotes.

**EDIT:**

Here's a suggestion of I would write the query (avoiding the use of ANSI joins, and subqueries).

```
SELECT  readings.mpancore,
        mtds.meterid,
        CASE  
            WHEN meter_type LIKE 'RCAM%' AND retrieval_method = 'R' THEN 'TRUE' 
            ELSE 'FALSE' 
        END AS "IS_SMART"
FROM    edmgr.mpan_status,
        edmgr.mtds,
        edmgr.D0019_reg,
        edmgr.readings
WHERE   mpan_status.mpancore = D0019_reg.metering_system_id
    AND mpan_status.mpancore = readings.mpancore
    AND readings.mpancore    = mtds.mpancore
    AND D0019_reg.metering_system_id = mtds.mpancore;
```

Comment: Morning Pjama,Thank you very much for taking the time to respond.  However, I have adhered to case-sensitivity and this is consistent throughout the query - it's only the error code which uses capitalisation! Should I convert all text in the query to upper-case?

Comment: No, don't convert it all to uppercase. Just be sure there discrepancy in capitalization. Is there a reason for creating table aliases in all the joins? (for instance edmgr.D0019_reg "D0019" ... which you then reference as D0019.metering_system_id)

Comment: Try avoiding aliases (just to simplify the query for now). Use D0019_reg instead of the D0019 alias.

Comment: Thanks again, Pjama.  However, it's now throwing back this error:

ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
*Cause:    
*Action:

(When removing aliases)

Comment: Well, at least the 00904 is solved. The ORA-01427 iss because you have subqueries within the main select statement (e.g. "IS_SMART") which are returning multiple rows instead of a single value. To be honest, this query looks like one gigantic mess that needs a major overhaul. You don't need to do individual Select stmts for each Case .

Comment: As if your help hasn't been useful enough already and I've not been audacious enough...would you have any suggestions insofar as returning singular values?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yeah, many of the in-house guys were left scratching their heads...back to the drawing board, I guess!  Thank you very much for your assistance.

Comment: I'll edit my answer with a suggestion of how I would write the query. (I personally don't use ANSI SQL Join syntax, instead I prefer to use FROM / WHERE statements.) This is more a matter of style, which would be a good point to read about if you're interested.

Comment: Yeah, I'm a bit of a newbie so realise that my scripting is likely to be a steaming pile of unoptimised mess!  Thanks again!

Comment: We've all gotta start somewhere. Please remember to mark the question as completed (if you're satisfied with the answer! :) Good luck with the query.

Comment: Thanks for the query amendment - however, it only seems to reference a single 'mpancore' value and the two associated 'meterid' values; endlessly it seems (256,141 rows before I terminated the query).

Comment: It may be useful to explain the purpose of the query and what I'm trying to achieve.  Basically, for each 'mpancore' (which is akin to a telephone number, only on the UK powergrid), there will be at least one 'meterid' attached.  I want to determine the type of meter (the 'IS_SMART' part of the query) as well as whether we have received a 'D0019' (which is a file that aggregates the usage for each individual 'mpancore').  If we have received a 'D0010' (information that asserts we have collected or submitted a reading for the 'mpancore', we should definitely have a 'D0019'.

Comment: The R1, R2 etc are settlement reconciliation runs, so I'm trying to find out which 'mpancore' requires 'D0019' values if we have received/sent a 'D0010'.  I hope this makes sense and thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: The query is probably under-constrained among other problems. This is way beyond the scope of the original question. Start off with a simplest query you can, and build it incrementally (checking the intermediate results). Please don't just execute my query -- I don't want to be responsible for crashing some system on the UK powergrid! :)

Comment: Why this: 'avoiding the use of ANSI joins'?

Comment: Matter of personal habit. ANSI joins would be fine if you're more comfortable using them.

Comment: Thanks Pjama - you've been invaluable.  I guess I've tried to run before I walk on this!  All of the case statements worked individually (prior to the removal of aliases), so I'm kind of stumped.  I might just write individual queries for each of the requirements and then amalgamate the results externally.  Thanks again!